# Create board for Catan with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to create the board for Catan game with SFML, and all i need is 19 shapes(hexagons) for each of them i can take all the 6 corners and the 6 sides, to build cities or roads.
For shapes i make this:

```
std::vector<sf::CircleShape> shape(19);
int n = 0;
int shape_y = 100;
for (size_t index = 0; index < shape.size(); index++) {
    if (index < 3) {
        sf::CircleShape sh(80, 6);
        sh.setPosition(200 + n, shape_y);
        sh.setFillColor(sf::Color::Magenta);
        shape[index] = sh;
        n += 140;
    }
    if (index == 3)
        n = 0;
    if (index < 7 && index >= 3) {
        sf::CircleShape sh(80, 6);
        sh.setPosition(130 + n, shape_y + 120);
        sh.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        shape[index] = sh;
        n += 140;
    }
    if (index == 7)
        n = 0;
    if (index >= 7 && index < 12) {
        sf::CircleShape sh(80, 6);
        sh.setPosition(60 + n, shape_y + 240);
        sh.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        shape[index] = sh;
        n += 140;
    }
    if (index == 12)
        n = 0;
    if (index >= 12 && index < 16) {
        sf::CircleShape sh(80, 6);
        sh.setPosition(130 + n, shape_y + 360);
        sh.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
        shape[index] = sh;
        n += 140;
    }
    if (index == 16)
        n = 0;
    if (index >= 16 && index < 19) {
        sf::CircleShape sh(80, 6);
        sh.setPosition(200 + n, shape_y + 480);
        sh.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
        shape[index] = sh;
        n += 140;
    }
}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

But how i get the corners and the sides from shapes? If i use getPoint(0) for corner, it don't draw the point where its belongs.
If this is not a good idea, what can i use for this problem?

Comment: Since `getPoint` returns a requested point I don't see how "how i get the corners and the sides from shapes" is a problem.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `sf::CircleShape::setOutlineThickness()`? This way you can modify the offset/position of the outline relative to the edges. Can't check it right now, but I'm pretty sure you can also set a negative width to make it to inwards.

Comment: Rereading your question I might have misunderstood you. Could you maybe use a simple drawing program to draw what you want so we can compare it to what you get?

Comment: @VTT yes, getPoint make this, but i want to draw that point exactly where it is, but it doesn`t do that. If i make this : sf::Vector2f pixel = sh.getPoint(0);
   cerc.setPosition(pixel.x,pixel.y);

Answer (score 7):

I implemented that feature long time ago, a simple way to achieve that.

My approach was to **represent each hexagon as a circle**. The drawn hexagon was embedded into that circle. To check if the mouse was over a corner or a side, I did a simple check:

- If the point was inside 3 circles simultaneously, it was a corner (the meeting corner of those 3 hexagons)
- If the point was inside 2 circles, it was a side.
- If the point was inside 1 circle, it was a whole hexagon

Proof of concept:

[image]

The blue hexagons conform the proper board, each of these have a red circle (larger than the hexagon itself).

The green hexagons are out of the board (they aren't part of the game board) and they help to know if mouse is over sides or corners of the outter hexagons.

Full code is in [my Github repository](https://github.com/alseether/Hex-Tile-Map), but is quite old and may be out of date